# How to iterate over elements of the same type in Android?

Tags: java, android

I have been working on a (probably bad, but I don't know enough about Android Studio) application for displaying objects from lists that may be on multiple lists (Magic cards that are in multiple decks), and because I'm bad I have a 21 checkbox view to represent each deck. When these are checked, it allows me to sort and filter and what have you, but I cannot figure out how to iterate over all of them without manually writing up a hard-coded array of their IDs.

Each of the checkboxes was created manually. If there is a better way to do this, feel free to answer with that as well/instead.

EDIT: I don't have any example code (aside from knowing that `findViewById(R.id.checkBox1)` returns the first checkbox), but here is a [picture of my current layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJd5Y.png). I am using a blank project with no special layouts or anything. All of the checkboxes are independent and the only thing they have in common is that they are on the same page.

Comment: One possibility is to give the parent view (the LinearLayout or whatever you're using) an id, and then grab a reference to it and loop using `getChildAt()` and check if `instanceof CheckBox` etc.

Comment: If you could provide some example code, that would be helpful! It sounds like you may want to look into using a [recycler view](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview?gclid=Cj0KCQjw0K-HBhDDARIsAFJ6UGgedwRp1-ApqyuiiKK1BwDZzAqukHt5aIOWODjC3bIodRrg8BlJ4yIaAj6cEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds) for your list